# Casting the output of Query.getResultList()

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, jpa

In my app, when the user requests the List of a model (SheetItem), a service queries the DB and returns the result to the controller

This is my Model:

```
  public class SheetItem
   {
       private long id;
       private String name;
       .. getters and setters and constructor 
   }
```

This is the service code:

```
public List<SheetItem> listSheets(int pageNumber) {
    Query query= em.createQuery("select id,name from SheetItem");
    query.setFirstResult(pageNumber*10);
    query.setMaxResults(10);
    return query.getResultList();   
}
```

And this is the controller:

```
@GetMapping("/list")
public @ResponseBody List<SheetItem> getAllSheets(@RequestParam("page") int pageNum){   
       List<SheetItem> realList = sheetServices.listSheets(pageNum);
       return   realList;
}
```

The problem is that the data returned to the user is not JSON formatted ( Even there is a "Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8" auto-generated header).
The output is :

```
[
    [
      1,
      "my first sheet"
    ],
    [
      2,
      "my second sheet"
    ]
]
```

When debugging the code, I notice that the type of members of the returned List is **Object**:

[image]

How can I convert the format to JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You return individual object fields ...and get a number and a string.

```
Query query= em.createQuery("select id,name from SheetItem");
```

Return the object of the required type...

```
Query query= em.createQuery("select sh from SheetItem sh");
```

...and get the correct JSON.

Comment: The select statement can be as simple as `"from SheetItem"` to achieve the same result

Answer (score 1):

Use `TypedQuery` to make sure you return the correct type:

```
public List<SheetItem> listSheets(int pageNumber) {
    TypedQuery<SheetItem> query = em.createQuery("from SheetItem", SheetItem.class);
    // ... this part is unchanged ...
    return query.getResultList();   
}
```